# Company moved eCommerce pages to a subdomain and saw other pages drop in rankings. Related?

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, ranking

At the end of June my company moved our website's ecommerce product pages to a subdomain. The site had previously be consolidated on www.company.com; to improve usability we migrated all ecommerce product pages to shop.company.com.

I just compared our rankings from July (after the move) to our rankings in June (before the move), and found that almost every ranking keyword had dropped. However, the pages which lost rankings are not related to the subdomain switch. (That is to say, only product pages were moved to the subdomain - www.company.com/product became shop.company.com/product. The pages that dropped in rankings include the homepage, the about page, etc., which were not moved to the "shop" subdomain.)

Could the migration of product pages to the subdomain be the cause of our loss in rankings, despite the fact that the pages which lost ranking were not moved to the subdomain?

Comment: Did you do 301 redirects for the pages that moved? If not, you hurt those pages. Now that they are worth less, they boost your other pages less (though weaker linking) and they suffer for it.

Comment: As well, you are not giving the search engines enough time. Large-scale changes to sites seriously disrupt the index and the entire (or nearly entire) site has to be crawled in order to recalculate the metrics required to perform in the SERPs as it should. Think about it, you just put into question many entries in Googles (assumption) index and now in order for Google to trust what they are serving in the SERPs are valid, it has to re-crawl the site, repopulate the index, and recalculate the metrics for your entire site. This will take a while.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you for your help! My developer did not do 301 redirects for the moved pages, but I am having him correct that now.

Comment: @closetnoc Thank you for your response! You are definitely right that there has been a lot of time between the rankings reports and I will be sure to monitor the rankings going forward as Google re-indexes the site.

Comment: I have been jerking a knot in Googles tail over and over again with changes to my site and now it is in the doldrums, however, I can see Google doing a massive re-indexing just in time for me to make some more changes. Ooopppsss!!! It happens from time to time. It always works out!